# I want to merge a text cell together with date cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, excel-2007

I need help writing this formula

=concatenate("(",c9,")"," ",d9)

and i want the result to look like this

(18) 12/31/2021 in the same cell

Comment: It would be helpful to know what's in each cell...

Comment: c9 is a number value and d9 is date value

Comment: I need help on how to convert date column from count to date on pivot table

Answer (score 0):

For the formula, try the following: `=CONCATENATE("(",C9,")"," ",TEXT(D9,"m/d/yyy"))`

In order to display dates in the Values area of a pivot table you could select summarize values by either Max or Min and then change the number format to date.